# Identifying a method/property of a scala class - possible mocks recording called method?

Tags: scala, properties, mocking

I'd like to be able to designate an arbitrary property (val or def) of a class which isn't defined in a easily mockable trait. The motivation is to provide flexible references to entities - a pair of 'value, property of an object to be matched against', like this:

```
case class Employee(id :Long, name :String)
case class Ref[E, T](value :T, property :Property[E])

def Ref[E, T](prop :E=>T, value :T) = new Ref(value, Property(prop))
```

to use it like:

```
val ref = Ref[Employee](_.name, "Motoko")
val major :Employee = repository(ref).head.get
```

The task is to implement Property class, so that any two calls in the line of

```
Property[Employee](_.name)
...
Property[Employee](e=> e.name)
```

will return equal instances and repository implementation can use an internal map Map[Property, Query] to create an appropriate select for the passed reference. My first attempt was to use javaassist to intercept and record method calls and used received overriden method as the property identifier, but it produced a NoSuchMethodError on some synthetic scala init method during mock creation before even reaching my handler. I feel it should be easily doable by some scala library like scalamock, but I wasn't able to find a relevant functionality in the API.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, could you provide more details? (What is `Property` class, how does the implementation look like?)

Comment: Property class is exacly what I want to implement. I'm not interested in any details, just that equals works as specified. Alternatively, I could attain this goal with a macro, but I believe they are better contained within libraries.